# How can I clear the notification center from Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, notifications, osx-mavericks

I really like [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier) and how it allows you to send things to the notification center.

It even has a handy feature to remove the notifications that *it* sent, for example if I spoofed a notification from another app like CodeKit, syntax being:

```
terminal-notifier -sender com.incident57.CodeKit -remove ALL
```

But I guess this application is not able to clear the notifications that it did not send, as the other messages are still hanging around:

[image: screenshot-with-shadow.png]

It's a great tool but it still leaves me wondering:

#### How can I clear the notification center from Terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might run an AppleScript like this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Notification Center"
    click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    delay 0.1
    repeat while exists button 1 of UI element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
        click button 1 of UI element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
    end repeat
    click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
end tell'
```

Comment: On 10.8 I get "75:110: execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t get menu bar 2 of process "Notification Center". Invalid index. (-1719)"

Comment: @slhck I got the same error in a 10.8 VM, but I just had to replace `menu bar 2` with `menu bar 1`.

Comment: I get the "can't find" error with both 1 and 2.